# Slow socket io communication in android

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, socket.io

I am using [Socket Io Java Client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) in Android to communicate via xhr-polling to my server side application written in python.

Problem is, its running perfect in android 2.3 based phones, but for Samsung higher versions (4.x), it takes more than 10 seconds to respond my request.

Same application is built in ios and hits same server, and it takes approx 3 seconds to get response back from server.

Can any please help me out with this problem, am I missing something, or its some limitation with 4.x Android socket communication ?

Comment: Did you ever reach any conclusions on this issue?  I see this all the time with my application, some higher-model phones are incredibly slow in sending messages to my server w/ socket.io.